# Puppet. add user and permissions from another node

Tags: puppet, cloud

We have 2 nodes

- first
  node 'db' {
  include postgresql::server
  }
- second
  node 'webapp' {
  include nginx
  include unicorn
  include postgresql::client
  }

how to make the second node could add the database user to the first node?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [exported resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/exported_resources.html).  Define a resource type for a postgresql user, export it from webapp, and collect it in db.